# Embed google calendar in rails

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to show Google calender in rails page. If i log in browser (in gmail account) i can see the Google calender with details in localhost if i sign out from Google account i can't see my calender details in localhost. How to fix this?

I am using iframe to embed Google calendar in rails.

```
require 'gmail'

class CalendarController < ApplicationController
  def event_display
    gmail = Gmail.new('username','password')
  end
end
```

In event_display.html.erb

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=vinothinibj%40gmail.com&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Asia%2FCalcutta" style=" border-width:0 " width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by looking into authentication (which I am struggling with right now).

Also note that the public's ability to view a private calendar via a private link is also being discontinued.

https://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=1631300&hl=en

-Markus

Comment: the page is no more available